# Input a SVG curve into a GN setup

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

I have a SVG curve from a client that I need to resample in a GN setup. I can't work out how to input it into the GN setup. Any way to do this?

Comment: Import SVG, switch *Fill Mode* to "None" in *Object Data Properties > Shape*, add *Geometry Nodes* modifier, do some cool stuff with the curve.

Comment: Great - thank you. I was looking for an actual 'curve input node'. I forget GN is a modifier concept.

Comment: If your question has been solved, please be so kind and mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted answer" so that this question will not continue to be displayed as unsolved. Thank you! Here you can find more information: [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you still haven't gotten a solution to your question, please be kind enough to address it.

Comment: The answer is in the comment above - I can't mark that as an answer.

Comment: No, this is just a comment, the answer is here below. The concept of this platform is that an answer is given to a question. If this answer is correct, it should be marked as "Accepted Answer". This is the only way to mark the post as solved and fulfill the idea of this platform. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can do that:

1. Import your SVG file via *File > Import* (the add-on "Import-Export: Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) 1.1 format" has to be activated)
2. In *Object Data Properties > Shape* switch the setting of *Fill Mode* to "None". This will not automatically fill the imported curve and convert it to a mesh.
3. Add the modifier *Geometry Nodes* and the node `Resample Curve`.

[image]